# How to select rows with id just larger than x in descending order

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

I would like to select 5 newer posts than post with `id` 15 in a descending order using only SQL. This query works but I would like to do that using just one `SELECT`. Any ideas?

```
SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id > 15 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5
            ) as reverse_ordered ORDER BY id DESC
```

The next query won't work because I want posts with ids 20-16, but this one would return the newest posts (e.g. 100-96 in case of 100 posts)

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id > 15 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Gaps in ids are possible, the numbers above are just as an example.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Why you want it to be a single query ? for simplicity or what ?

Comment: Simplicity and curiosity.

Comment: Ok, lets wait for some interesting answer

Comment: If your ids dont have gaps (you said you want 20-16), you can use `select * from posts where id < 21 order by id desc limit 5`. Otherwise you need your double `select`.

Comment: Yeah, gaps are unfortunately possible :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most human beings would not consider this *simpler*.  But, it doesn't use a subquery:

```
select unnest( (array_agg(p.id order by p.id asc)::int[])[1:5]) as id
from posts p
where p.id >= 15
order by id desc;
```

The method with the subquery should be superior performance-wise.

Comment: So far the best answer, although I must admit I was hoping for something a little bit different :)

Comment: Is it possible to such magics in `SQL Server` without `Sub-Query`

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the query you *have* is the optimum and much faster than any alternative when supported with an index on `id`. It resolves to a single index scan. The cost for the 2nd sort is negligible. Not sure why you want a single `SELECT`, but it's probably a misunderstanding.

As proof of concept, while we entertain this wild goose chase: you asked for `SELECT *`, not for `SELECT id`:

```
SELECT (unnest((array_agg(p ORDER BY p.id))[1:5])).*
FROM   posts p
WHERE  p.id > 15
ORDER  BY id DESC;
```